# Facing some issue to print the API response values in one sentence

Tags: api, response, postman

I am trying to assert and print the response, for that need help.

Below is response body:

```
{  
   "createdIncidents":[  
      {  
         "incidentRef":"I0000000",
         "personName":"API API",
         "personType":"Patient"
      },
      {  
         "incidentRef":"I0000000",
         "personName":"Ballarat HelpDesk",
         "personType":"Staff"
      },
      {  
         "incidentRef":"I0000000",
         "personName":"test api",
         "personType":"Visitor"
      },
      {  
         "incidentRef":"I0000000",
         "personName":null,
         "personType":"Hazard"
      }
   ]
}
```

I am trying to print `incidentRef` and `personType` together in a string.

For that, I am using this code:

```
var data = JSON.parse(responseBody);
data.createdIncidents.forEach(function(incident, personT) {
    var personType = "personType" + personT.personType;
    var incidents = "incidentRef" + incident.incidentRef;
    var pt = tests["incidents created for " + personType ] = 'personType';
    var inc = tests["incidents number is " + incidents] = 'incidents';
    tests["incidents created for" +inc && + pt ];
});
```

Here it is not reading the second items inside the function.
In a separate function declaration it works fine.

I want to print it as:

```
"incidentRef": "I0000000 is created for "personType": "Hazard""
```

Comment: It's really confusing to follow the question - Do you just want to log out each `personType` and `incidentRef`? What are you trying to check?

Comment: I want to assert the response and display that as "incidentRef": "I0000000 is created for "personType": "Hazard" , for the response that is given above

Comment: I've updated my answer to print out what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

This would log each item from the `createdIncidents` array to the console - Unsure what you're actually trying to assert against though:

```
_.each(pm.response.json().createdIncidents, (arrItem) => {
    console.log(`Incident Ref: ${arrItem.incidentRef} is created for Person Type: ${arrItem.personType}`)
})
```

Given your response data, this would be the output:

```
Incident Ref: I0000000 is created for Person Type: Patient
Incident Ref: I0000000 is created for Person Type: Staff
Incident Ref: I0000000 is created for Person Type: Visitor
Incident Ref: I0000000 is created for Person Type: Hazard
```

This could be wrapped in a `pm.test()` and the different items can be asserted against using the `pm.expect()` syntax.

This is very basic and is very hardcoded but it would check the data in your example:

```
pm.test('Check the response', () => {
    _.each(pm.response.json().createdIncidents, (arrItem) => {
        pm.expect(arrItem.incidentRef).to.equal("I0000000")
        pm.expect(arrItem.personType).to.be.oneOf(['Patient','Staff','Visitor','Hazard'])
        console.log(`Incident Ref: ${arrItem.incidentRef} is created for Person Type: ${arrItem.personType}`)
    })
})
```

Comment: DANNY- Thanks for help, one more thing, like Incident Ref: number changes every time, to read that and print like above, what would be the script

Comment: The results will always be logged out to the console in the way you want, the check is very flaky as it would fail if the ref Id is different or the type isn't one in the list. I don't know enough about your implementation to tell you the exact 'answer' to every piece of data you need to check. This will hopefully give you a starting point.